# Rails get from view table column name and value of select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I now, that question could be non good for so, but need help:
In my rails haml view i have such code:

```
%table.table.table-striped
  = form_tag :admin_other_price_upload do
    %tr    
      - @csv.first.length.times do |n|
        %th
          = n + 1
          %br/
          =select_tag "s"+(n+1).to_s, options_for_select([["Брэнд", "Brand"], ["Артикул","Article"], ["Наименование","Descr"], ["Цена","Price"], ["Количество","Quantity"], ["Дополнительно","Other"], ["Поле кроссов","Cross"]]), :prompt => 'Все', :id => "select-value"
*********************************
```

so as you can see i'm setting to all select's name like s(n+1) and value one from list. But how can i get them both in controller method? I need it becouse i have dynamic table. I will explain it on example:

So i have table with select's

```
name = s1 (value = Brand) | name = s2 (value = Price)
```

so i need in controller to get not only that s1 => Brand, but also get this 1 from s1
So if param look's like
[
  s1 => {Brand}
]
I need to get for my calculation s1 not value, but s1 as string (**simple i need to find in params, which value has Brand and select it as a value**)
So for Brand i need to select s1, and set as s1 value s1, how could i do it?

Comment: I dont really get your point here ... What you posted will generate params like `params[:s1] = 'Brand'` and `params[:s2] = 'Article'` (Brand and Article are random values). What do you want to extract/get from these params?

Comment: @MrYoshiji i want to see for example in puts s2 not Article, but s2..... So params[:s2] = s2 i want to see

Comment: a loop like `params.each do |key, value|` will allow you to access to the 's2' with the `key` word

Comment: @MrYoshiji or another solution to get where brand is set etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have understood you, but not sure.

```
# let's say your params hash is like:
params = { :action => 'show', :controller => 'articles', 
           :s1 => 'Article', :s2 => 'Brand', :s3 => 'Price', ... }

brand_param = params.select{ |key, value| value == 'Brand' }
# => { :s2 => 'Brand' }
which_s_is_brand = brand_param.keys.first.to_s
# => 's2'
```

Comment: also: if i need to delete first symbol (s) is it better to write .to_s.slice!(0).to_i or just .to_i ?